# Tracking game progress with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We are in the process of creating an Android game in which we want to use Google Analytics to track the users progress and engagement.

I have read through the Custom Dimensions/Metrics docs and got some good insights on how Analytics can be used for games. I am not completely sure though how to model our usecase though.

The game is a board game where we have three different modes in which you can play the game. In addition we have 10 different difficulty levels that can be applied on a mode.

- Mode 1 progresses linear though the difficulty
- Mode 2 lets the user choose a difficulty
- Mode 3 has no difficulty. It is a local player vs player.

The questions i want to ask are:

- How often to users play a particular mode?
- Which mode is the most popular?
- What difficulty level do they play in a particular mode?
- What is the finishing rate for a certain difficulty level in a mode?

I guess a clever combination of custom dimensions and metrics could answer those questions. If anybody is willing to hint me in the right direction i would be very thankful.